# How to rebind/consume queue from channel?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I am using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) to transfer messages in my node.js server.

Here is my code to listen on queue:

```
channel.consume(queue, handler1, { noAck: true })
```

Now, I want to update the consumer to listen the same queue

Like this:

```
channel.consume(queue, handler2, { noAck: true })
```

I try to unbindQueue or deleteQueue but don't know why the error `Unhandled rejection IllegalOperationError: Channel closing` is thrown

Comment: Cloud be that the node.js lib doesn't support multiple consumer on the same channel maybe?

Comment: @rlanvin I just want to update the consumer, still one consumer on same queue.

Comment: Alright I see. Then in this case in theory you need to do a `cancel` with the consumerTag (returned by consume). Did you try that?